# How to count the images displayed in the slideshow?

Tags: python, list, loops, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to display images as a slideshow on raspberry pi. I need help with counting the times each image displayed in the slideshow over a period of 60 mins.
ex: If there are 20 images in a folder, I want to count how many times each of those 20 images were displayed in the tkinter frame in 60 mins.

Below is my code.

```
class gui:
 def __init__(self,mainWin):
    
    self.counter = 0
    self.mainWin = mainWin
    self.mainWin.title("picture frame")

    self.frame = tk.Frame(mainWin)
    self.img = tk.Label(self.frame)
    self.frame.place(relheight = 0.85, relwidth = 0.9, relx = 0.05, rely = 0.05)
    
    self.img.pack()
    self.pic()
            
def pic(self):
    self.pic_list = []
    for name in glob.glob(r'image_path*'):
        val = name
        self.pic_list.append(val)
    
    self.image_list = enumerate(self.pic_list) 
       
        
    if self.counter == len(self.pic_list) - 1:
        self.counter = 0
    else:
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        
    self.file = self.pic_list[self.counter]
    self.load = Image.open(self.file)
    

    
    self.pic_width = self.load.size[0]
    self.pic_height = self.load.size[1]
    
    self.real_aspect = self.pic_width / self.pic_height
    
    self.cal_width = int(self.real_aspect * 800)
    
    self.load2 = self.load.resize((self.cal_width,800))
    
    self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load2)
    self.img.config(image = self.render)
    self.img.image = self.render
    root.after(5000,self.pic)

  root = tk.Tk()
  myprog = gui(root)
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it necessary to load the image list every time `pic()` is executed?

Comment: Since the pic method is called every 5 seconds, (60 * 60) // (5 * len(self.pic_list)).